# What is the cleanest way to calculate instance variables in initialize?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Say I have a class that defines a collection of my days and how wacky they are. Is it better to initialize my @scores variable in the initialize function like so:

```
class WackyDayScorer
  attr_reader :scores
  def initialize(start = Time.now, max = 90.days)
    @start  = start
    @limit  = start - max
    @scores = get_scores
  end

private
  def get_scores
    result = []
    t = @start.clone
    until t < max
      result << score_wackiness(t)
      t -= 1.day
    end
    result
  end
end
```

or initialize it in the get_scores method like so:

```
class WackyDayScorer
  attr_reader :scores

  def initialize(start = Time.now, max = 90.days)
    @start = start
    @limit = start - max
    get_scores
  end

private
  def get_scores
    @scores = []
    t = @start.clone
    until t < max
      @scores << score_wackiness(t)
      t -= 1.day
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is just plain wrong. You are saying

```
@scores = get_scores
```

But `get_scores` does not return a useful value, so this is nuts. Instead, `get_scores` sets `@scores` directly and internally as a side effect.

The second one is at least coherent.

Personally, though, I would not do *either* of the things *you* do. I would say what you say the first time:

```
@scores = get_scores
```

But my implementation of `get_scores` would not touch any ivar. It would *return* an actual value:

```
  def get_scores
    scores = []
    # do stuff to scores
    return scores # or simply, scores
  end
```

Comment: I would not _return_ any value, since idiomatic Ruby uses implicit returns from method invocations.

Comment: Right, but local variable value to be returned still needs to be in dead last position so as to *be* returned implicitly.

Comment: Fixed the bug you pointed out in the first example, thx. Seems like you're saying the first solution is the one you would pick.

Comment: In your edited version, yes, exactly. Unfortunately your edited version turns my answer into nonsense. :(

Comment: Oh, and the *reason* I like the first way better (now) is that it is dead clear what `initialize` is doing: it's setting the three ivars. In the second one, it is not at all obvious, without looking in two places, what is going on.

Comment: My motto being, try to write code you stand a chance of being able to read the next day! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle something in initialization, create a private method to handle the calculation and then set the instance variable in #initialize. I wouldn't set it in the method in case you want to reuse that calculation elsewhere in the class without wiping out your instance variable.

```
class WackyDayScorer
  attr_accessor :scores

  def initialize(start = DateTime.now, max = 90.days)
    @start = start
    @limit = start - max
    @scores = calculate_scores
  end

private

  def calculate_scores
    (@limit..@start).to_a.map { |date_time| score_wackiness(date_time) }
  end
end
```

In #calculate_scores, we are creating a range between the limit date and the start (counting backwards, as you were doing) and sending each result to the #score_wackiness method.

Comment: I decided against this because this value will always be calculated every time someone uses this class. Why put off the inevitable?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend explicitly defining the getter for scores, memoizing the calculation and skipping all the ceremony:

```
class WackyDayScorer
  def initialize(start = Time.now, max = 90.days)
    @start  = start
    @limit  = start - max
  end

  def scores
    @scores ||= begin
      result = []
      t = @start.clone
      until t < max
        result << score_wackiness(t)
        t -= 1.day
      end
      result
    end
  end
end
```

This is basically what you are doing anyway, but it's more direct.

Comment: I like this. But I don't think I'd call it "memoization"; it's just lazy initialization (thru the getter).

Comment: @matt Using the `||=` and assigning it to an instance variable *is* memoization. You can [read more about what memoization is here](http://www.reference.com/browse/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: I don't agree and I don't think you're reading the article correctly. Memoization is the technique of storing the value of f(x) for *each different x* under some expensive function f, so that if the same call is made again for the same argument value, it doesn't have to be recalculated. See for example https://github.com/djberg96/memoize

Comment: `||=` is merely standard ruby idiom for initialization of an instance variable

Comment: And if we store the result of the calculation when we don't supply a value for `x` in `f(x)` so that, when a second call is made to `f`, it doesn't have to recalculate the value... seems like memoization to me. I'm alright with being wrong here, but this is the first time I've ever seen someone argue that the use of `||=` in Ruby is *not* memoization. Googling various phrases related to Ruby and memoization seems to turn up a lot of misinformation if `||=` is truly not memoization.

Comment: `||=` is just a cute shorthand for e.g. `x = y unless x`, i.e. assign y to x unless x has a non-nil non-false value already. It comes in handy for instance variables because instance variables in ruby report themselves as nil if they don't have a value yet. I don't see what that has to do with memoization. I still like your answer best, though. :) But I would describe what you are doing, as I said, as lazy initialization.